# Kotlin and Java project in Eclipse, NoClassDefFoundError, where are the class files?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, kotlin

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44266042/kotlin-setup-via-gradle-on-eclipse) the basic configuration of Kotlin + Java + Gradle in Eclipse is described. It allows me to create Kotlin code. The Kotlin and Java natures are correctly present. Unfortunately, the code does not run. Not as Kotlin application nor as JUnit test.

When my (i.e. created by me) Kotlin class is called from Java code, it yields a NoClassDefFoundError. When the same test/application is run from Gradle or IntelliJ the code runs correctly.

My investigation thus far has uncovered that the class files in the bin folder are not there to be found when executing.

**Using the buildship plugin**

The image below shows that the `src` tree exists. All Java compile classes are in the `src` tree. The `kotlin_bin` folder has the correct folders, but no files.

[image: Eclipse bin folder]

**Using gradlew eclipse and import .project files**

This results in the same behavior. I prefer buildship to manage gradle.

**Tool versions**

I'm using:

- Eclipse 2019-03 or 2019-06
- Kotlin eclipse plugin 0.8.17
- Kotlin-gradle eclipse plugin 0.8.17
- Buildship plugin 3.1.0
- Gradle 5.4.1
- Kotlin 1.3
- Java 11

Any tips on how to proceed? I would like to be able to run in Eclipse. We're adding a small Kotlin part to the project, I would prefer not to force my team to switch to IntelliJ.

Comment: Not sure what your constraints are, but it's a pretty outdated version of Kotlin. it's on 1.3+ now, if it's possible, you might want to start by updating it if you can.

Comment: I’m sorry. It’s the kotlin eclipse plugin version. Will correct the list of used tools.

Comment: Hi. Same here. Any progress on your side?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Building via gradlew on the command line or IntelliJ IDEA, but no running inside Eclipse.

Comment: @MichielLeegwater Thanks for quick answer. I think I'll change to IDEA/Gradle for now. Just in order to make things work and fix the we-should-also-be-able-to-work-with-eclipse-problem later.

Comment: I just observed something strange: When I try to configure a different Java Build Path in project properties via Browse-button, the file view offers a kotlin_bin folder (including exactly the subfolders it should have), but this folder is not really present on disk. Is this where you got your screenshot from or is it showing a "realistic file situation"?

Comment: The screenshot is an actual screenshot of a part of eclipse. If you look at the .project file there is a linkedResource. I’ve been told this explains the screenshot and no files on the file system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue seems to be an issue with the Eclipse plugin. See [KE-344](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KE-344). All symptoms seem to match.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, when you get a `NoClassDefFoundError` it means that the class loader cannot find your classes because your class "disappeared". In Eclipse, this is typically fixed with a simple "Clean Project" to force rebuilding. On the other hand, `ClassNotFoundException` means something went wrong with your classpath. If cleaning the project and rebuilding doesn't work, I think it might still be possible something could be wrong with your classpath. To check your classpath in Eclipse, change to the Navigator View  and open your `.classpath` file (see image below).

[image: Navigator View]

Then, check your `classpathentry` nodes to see "output" path. Your `.classpath` should contains mappings for your source location, your output location (where compiled classes reside), as well as references to your JRE container and any libraries imported by the project. Make sure all of these entries are correct.

My guess is that your classpath is not right. To fix, follow these instructions: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html.  One of those suggestions should work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems very Java only, therefore I am not sure yet that the reply will point out the problem. A superficial check yielded: It seems that there is something peculiar going on. The kotlin compiled classes are put in a virtual folder called kotlin_bin. At runtime the virtual folder is not used. I’ve edited the classpath to no avail. Will continue investigation later this weekend.

Comment: Thanks for providing the explanation. It does not yet result in a solved situation. Understanding has improved due to this answer.

Comment: @MichielLeegwater, it appears that support for Kotlin in Eclipse is broken: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/eclipse-kotlin-plug-in-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-eclipse-jdt-internal-ui-javaeditor-compilationuniteditor/10789

Answer (score 0):

since i branch my project ,then refactor project name suit next feature.
then my project can't find kotlin class.i search google and stackoverflow no effect.
i diff project with scm HEAD version, discover the differece in

.project

```
<linkedResources>
    <link>
        <name>kotlin_bin</name>
        <type>2</type>
        <locationURI>org.jetbrains.kotlin.core.filesystem:/**YOUR_PROJECT**/kotlin_bin</locationURI>
    </link>
</linkedResources>
```

then i fix project name in .project file. it was fixed after rebuild